# await operator not stopping continuation of other method calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, wait

I have three methods that look like below

```
private async Task checkPhotoLibraryAccess()
{
    PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization(status =>
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            //stuff here
        }
    }

}

private async Task checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus()
{
    var status = AVCaptureDevice.GetAuthorizationStatus(AVMediaType.Video);
    switch (status)
    {
        //stuff here
    }
}

private void displayAppBar()
{
     AppBar.IsVisible = true;
}
```

I would like the execution of the first two methods to complete before calling the third. I have researched the issue and have found ways of doing so using the await operator and Wait() method. However my implementations has not worked. Here is my code below.

Attempt 1

```
private async void MyMethod() 
{
    await checkPhotoLibraryAccess();
    await checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus();
    displayAppBar(); //THIS IS CALLED BEFORE COMPLETION OF TWO ABOVE
}
```

Attempt 2

```
private async void MyMethod()
{
    checkPhotoLibraryAccess().Wait();
    checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus().Wait();
    displayAppBar(); //SAME ISSUE
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Do the `checkPhotoLibraryAccess` and the `checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus` methods contain any `await`s?

Comment: @RyeGuy constructors are not allowed to be `async` and you should not block on `async` methods with `.Wait`. What you need would be [Async Initialization](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: Sounds like you need to `await` `RequestAuthorization()` (and make it awaitable).

Comment: @SLaks yes I am going to try and make an await for the RequestAuthorization. I have moved the method calls outside of the constructor into a new method

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid C#, never mind is it a [mcve]. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to provide a good answer. Suffice to say, if your `displayAppBar()` is executing before you expect it to, your expectations are flawed, and the tasks returned by the preceding methods are completing before you realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yacoub Massad and @SLaks reminded me that in order for await to work on a method call, the method needs to contain an await operator.

So I changed my PhotoLibraryAccess method to contain an await operator and placed its method call right before the DisplayAppBar call.

```
private async Task checkPhotoLibraryAccess()
{
    var status = await PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorizationAsync(); 
    //stuff here
}
```

And then ...

```
private async void MyMethod()
{
     checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus(); //Removed async Task stuff
     await checkPhotoLibraryAccess();
     displayButtons(); //IT WORKS
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a third method to be executed based on the completion of two other methods you use the `WhenAll` method of the `Task` class.

```
var t1 = CheckPhotoLibraryAccess();
var t2 = CheckDeviceAuthorization();

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ContinueWith(t => DisplayAppBar());
```